# RuntimeError: Cost Function returns nan values in its 1th output

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am working on a temporal model to predict future events. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B5FTnKpohPlywiRKQBXNjfR4fwka8FiE/view?usp=sharing) to my colab notebook. I am facing an issue trying to train the model. I am getting NaN values for Train and valid loss. The loss function is a joint loss consisting of the cross entropy loss and the squared loss.  Link to the blog [here](https://sparalic.github.io/post/using-electronic-health-records-to-predict-future-diagnosis-codes-with-gated-recurrent-units/).

Tried following solution which didn`t worked -
Smaller learning rate - 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001

```
class cost_function():
    def __init__(self, yhat, y, L_2=0.001, logEps=1e-8):
        # logEps : log epsilon, very small positive value greater that 0.0
        # CE = - [ ln(y*)(y) + ln(1-y*)(1-y) ],

        self.yhat = yhat
        self.y = y
       
        self.logEps = logEps
        self.L_2 = L_2
        
        self.W_out = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(hiddenDimSize, numClass)*0.01)
        
    def cross_entropy(self):
        ce = -(self.y * torch.log(self.yhat + self.logEps) + (1. - self.y) * torch.log(1. - self.yhat + self.logEps))
        print("Inside CrossEntrophy Loss fn : ", ce)
        return ce

    def prediction_loss(self):
        # return  (torch.sum(torch.sum(self.cross_entropy(), dim=0),dim=1)).float()/  lengths.float()
        
        tmp_tensor = torch.sum(self.cross_entropy(), dim=0)
        print("Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0", tmp_tensor)
        print("Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1", torch.sum(tmp_tensor,dim=1))
        print("Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result ", (torch.sum(tmp_tensor,dim=1)).float()/  lengths.float())
        return (torch.sum(tmp_tensor,dim=1)).float()/  lengths.float()
        
    def cost(self):
        print("Inside Cost fn :", torch.mean(self.prediction_loss()) + self.L_2 * (self.W_out ** 2).sum())
        return torch.mean(self.prediction_loss()) + self.L_2 * (self.W_out ** 2).sum() # regularize
```

build_EHRNN class -  I have made modification in the forward method params to resolve the 'h' is not defined error.

```
torch.manual_seed(1)

class build_EHRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputDimSize=4894, hiddenDimSize=[200,200], batchSize=100, embSize=200, numClass=4894, dropout=0.5, logEps=1e-8):
        super(build_EHRNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.inputDimSize = inputDimSize
        self.hiddenDimSize = hiddenDimSize
        self.numClass = numClass
        self.embSize = embSize
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.logEps = logEps
        
        
        # Embedding inputs
        self.W_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.inputDimSize, self.embSize).cuda())
        self.b_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.embSize).cuda())
        
        self.W_out = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hiddenDimSize, self.numClass).cuda())
        self.b_out = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.numClass).cuda())
         
        self.params = [self.W_emb, self.W_out, 
                       self.b_emb, self.b_out] 
    
    # def forward(self,x, y, h, lengths, mask):
    def forward(self,x, y, lengths, mask):
        self.emb = torch.tanh(torch.matmul(x, self.W_emb) + self.b_emb)
        input_values = self.emb
        self.outputs = [input_values]
        for i, hiddenSize in enumerate([self.hiddenDimSize, self.hiddenDimSize]):  # iterate over layers
            rnn = EHRNN(self.inputDimSize,hiddenSize,self.embSize,self.batchSize,self.numClass) # calculate hidden states
            hidden_state = []
            h = self.init_hidden().cuda()
            for i,seq in enumerate(input_values): # loop over sequences in each batch
                h = rnn(seq, h)                    
                hidden_state.append(h)    
            hidden_state = self.dropout(torch.stack(hidden_state))    # apply dropout between layers
            input_values = hidden_state
       
        y_linear = torch.matmul(hidden_state, self.W_out)  + self.b_out # fully connected layer
        yhat = F.softmax(y_linear, dim=1)  # yhat
        yhat = yhat*mask[:,:,None]   # apply mask
        
        # Loss calculation
        cross_entropy = -(y * torch.log(yhat + self.logEps) + (1. - y) * torch.log(1. - yhat + self.logEps))
        last_step = -torch.mean(y[-1] * torch.log(yhat[-1] + self.logEps) + (1. - y[-1]) * torch.log(1. - yhat[-1] + self.logEps))
        prediction_loss = torch.sum(torch.sum(cross_entropy, dim=0),dim=1)/ torch.cuda.FloatTensor(lengths)
        cost = torch.mean(prediction_loss) + 0.000001 * (self.W_out ** 2).sum() # regularize
        return (yhat, hidden_state, cost)

    def init_hidden(self):
        return torch.zeros(self.batchSize, self.hiddenDimSize)  # initial state
```

model training

```
artificalData_seqs = np.array(pickle.load(open(os.path.join(GOOGLE_DRV_PATH,BASE_DIR,'data.encodedDxs'),'rb')))
train, test, valid = load_data(artificalData_seqs, artificalData_seqs)

batchSize = 50     # decreased from 100 to 50
n_batches = int(np.ceil(float(len(train[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1
n_batches_valid = int(np.ceil(float(len(valid[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1
model = build_EHRNN(inputDimSize=4894, hiddenDimSize=200, batchSize=50, embSize=200, numClass=4894, dropout=0.5, logEps=1e-8)
model = model.to(device)



 import torch.nn.functional as F
import pdb

optimizer = torch.optim.Adadelta(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001, rho=0.95)
epochs = 10

counter = 0
# with torch.autograd.detect_anomaly():
for e in range(epochs):
    for x, y in train_dl:
        x, y , mask, lengths = padding(x, y, inputDimSize, numClass)
        output, h = model(x, mask)
        
        loss = cost_function(output, y).cost()
        # pdb.set_trace()
        loss.backward()
        print("loss ",loss)
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 5) # Constraining the weight matrix directly == regularization. 
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
            model.eval()
            val_loss = []
            for x_valid, y_valid in valid_dl:
                    x_val, y_val, mask, lengths = padding(x_valid, y_valid, inputDimSize, numClass)
                    outputs_val, hidden_val = model(x_val,  mask)
                    loss = cost_function(outputs_val, y_val).cost()
                    val_loss.append(loss.item())
            model.train()

            print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, epochs),
                                "Step: {}...".format(counter),
                                "Training Loss: {:.4f}...".format(loss.item()),
                                "Val Loss: {:.4f}".format(torch.mean(torch.tensor(val_loss))))
```

Error (Start getting NaNs in the loss)

```
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[0.1008, 0.1539, 0.1211,  ..., 0.1533, 0.1218, 0.1418],
        [0.0253, 0.0449, 0.0249,  ..., 0.0439, 0.0134, 0.0332],
        [0.0306, 0.0799, 0.0570,  ..., 0.0790, 0.0484, 0.0678],
        ...,
        [0.0253, 0.0450, 0.0249,  ..., 0.0439, 0.0134, 0.0332],
        [0.0253, 0.0450, 0.0249,  ..., 0.0439, 0.0134, 0.0332],
        [0.0038, 0.0106, 0.0106,  ..., 0.0098, 0.0004, 0.0106]],
       grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([  372.4754,   133.2620,   219.1195,    37.5425,   141.3354,    37.5070,
          229.2947,     0.0000,   379.1829,   217.3962,    80.1226,    37.5074,
          138.4665,    82.1034,    89.7893,    81.8173,    92.8159,   141.8856,
           95.9898,   216.0511,   133.2535,   385.0391,   369.4958,   244.9362,
           37.5088,    37.5087,   141.6083,     0.0000,    95.3367,    37.5074,
          735.0569,   378.0407,    37.5135,    40.7778,    82.0872,   225.9998,
          216.6189,   379.0732,    81.4742,   144.4226,    93.3905,   214.0228,
           37.5078,   224.0793,    88.3753,    41.2919,   140.4855,    37.5086,
          226.6366,   148.7171,   137.9226, 13887.5811,    81.1428,    84.6804,
          226.6779,    37.5065,   223.8841,   220.5979,    83.2484,    37.5080,
           84.5247,   384.2115,    80.1173,     0.0000,   146.9714,    37.6982,
          134.6618,    84.1838,    37.5421,   730.5516,    37.5085,     0.0000,
          215.1523,   136.5673,    81.2887,    37.5080,    94.4181,   140.6268,
          133.9295,   136.2485,    80.1173,   386.2103,    39.0282,     0.0000,
           37.5055,    42.1506,    80.1662,   228.5819,    39.3403,   138.7672,
         1768.6033,   143.5350,    40.2060,   147.7809,    37.5085,   380.9214,
          750.6883,   141.0447,   136.9028,    37.5049],
       grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([5., 3., 4., 1., 3., 1., 4., 0., 5., 4., 2., 1., 3., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3.,
        2., 4., 3., 5., 5., 4., 1., 1., 3., 0., 2., 1., 6., 5., 1., 1., 2., 4.,
        4., 5., 2., 3., 2., 4., 1., 4., 2., 1., 3., 1., 4., 3., 3., 9., 2., 2.,
        4., 1., 4., 4., 2., 1., 2., 5., 2., 0., 3., 1., 3., 2., 1., 6., 1., 0.,
        4., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 3., 3., 2., 5., 1., 0., 1., 1., 2., 4., 1., 3.,
        7., 3., 1., 3., 1., 5., 6., 3., 3., 1.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([  74.4951,   44.4207,   54.7799,   37.5425,   47.1118,   37.5070,
          57.3237,       nan,   75.8366,   54.3491,   40.0613,   37.5074,
          46.1555,   41.0517,   44.8946,   40.9086,   46.4080,   47.2952,
          47.9949,   54.0128,   44.4178,   77.0078,   73.8992,   61.2340,
          37.5088,   37.5087,   47.2028,       nan,   47.6683,   37.5074,
         122.5095,   75.6081,   37.5135,   40.7778,   41.0436,   56.5000,
          54.1547,   75.8146,   40.7371,   48.1409,   46.6952,   53.5057,
          37.5078,   56.0198,   44.1876,   41.2919,   46.8285,   37.5086,
          56.6591,   49.5724,   45.9742, 1543.0646,   40.5714,   42.3402,
          56.6695,   37.5065,   55.9710,   55.1495,   41.6242,   37.5080,
          42.2623,   76.8423,   40.0586,       nan,   48.9905,   37.6982,
          44.8873,   42.0919,   37.5421,  121.7586,   37.5085,       nan,
          53.7881,   45.5224,   40.6443,   37.5080,   47.2090,   46.8756,
          44.6432,   45.4162,   40.0587,   77.2421,   39.0282,       nan,
          37.5055,   42.1506,   40.0831,   57.1455,   39.3403,   46.2557,
         252.6576,   47.8450,   40.2060,   49.2603,   37.5085,   76.1843,
         125.1147,   47.0149,   45.6343,   37.5049], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([2., 1., 1., 2., 3., 5., 3., 3., 1., 4., 2., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 5., 2.,
        4., 2., 1., 4., 2., 5., 3., 0., 4., 7., 6., 4., 4., 1., 7., 1., 3., 3.,
        5., 3., 5., 5., 4., 2., 2., 4., 1., 5., 6., 2., 5., 5., 2., 1., 3., 1.,
        4., 4., 3., 3., 0., 2., 2., 4., 2., 2., 1., 0., 3., 2., 3., 0., 1., 2.,
        4., 4., 5., 1., 1., 3., 3., 2., 5., 0., 2., 6., 5., 5., 5., 1., 2., 4.,
        0., 2., 6., 1., 2., 0., 1., 1., 2., 3.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([3., 2., 4., 4., 6., 1., 1., 4., 2., 2., 4., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 3., 1.,
        2., 3., 4., 2., 2., 3., 2., 0., 1., 3., 4., 1., 2., 3., 4., 3., 3., 1.,
        2., 3., 3., 2., 1., 4., 6., 3., 4., 2., 3., 0., 1., 1., 3., 7., 2., 3.,
        4., 2., 3., 0., 3., 3., 2., 1., 1., 3., 6., 2., 2., 3., 2., 3., 3., 2.,
        1., 2., 5., 3., 4., 2., 5., 3., 5., 5., 5., 3., 2., 1., 4., 3., 3., 3.,
        1., 4., 3., 2., 5., 3., 6., 4., 3., 2.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([4., 6., 2., 2., 4., 5., 0., 3., 2., 3., 4., 3., 3., 3., 4., 3., 0., 1.,
        2., 2., 4., 2., 4., 4., 1., 0., 3., 0., 5., 5., 1., 2., 3., 2., 2., 3.,
        1., 2., 1., 2., 3., 1., 3., 1., 3., 0., 4., 2., 1., 6., 2., 2., 0., 1.,
        4., 4., 2., 2., 0., 3., 5., 5., 5., 5., 3., 4., 4., 4., 5., 4., 2., 2.,
        3., 1., 5., 6., 3., 4., 1., 3., 5., 1., 3., 2., 3., 6., 2., 4., 3., 2.,
        3., 2., 4., 1., 2., 2., 1., 2., 3., 4.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([1., 5., 1., 5., 3., 0., 1., 4., 3., 3., 5., 5., 2., 0., 1., 2., 3., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 4., 1., 4., 2., 1., 3., 4., 0., 4., 2.,
        0., 4., 1., 1., 2., 3., 3., 5., 1., 3., 2., 3., 1., 1., 3., 6., 3., 0.,
        2., 3., 2., 3., 3., 4., 1., 5., 2., 6., 2., 1., 5., 3., 2., 1., 3., 5.,
        2., 0., 3., 0., 1., 3., 3., 2., 3., 1., 2., 4., 1., 2., 7., 2., 7., 2.,
        2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 4., 2., 2., 3.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([2., 2., 1., 4., 3., 2., 2., 4., 5., 2., 3., 1., 1., 2., 3., 1., 3., 1.,
        3., 1., 6., 4., 2., 2., 0., 4., 1., 0., 2., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2.,
        3., 1., 3., 2., 0., 1., 3., 2., 4., 1., 2., 1., 6., 2., 1., 2., 1., 2.,
        2., 1., 1., 1., 4., 1., 0., 2., 2., 2., 3., 6., 5., 1., 1., 3., 3., 3.,
        1., 4., 4., 2., 4., 2., 3., 7., 1., 1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 1., 4., 2., 3.,
        1., 2., 3., 2., 7., 0., 2., 3., 4., 4.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([1., 2., 6., 7., 2., 1., 1., 3., 1., 2., 2., 4., 3., 3., 4., 3., 2., 2.,
        5., 2., 1., 3., 2., 2., 2., 1., 4., 3., 2., 2., 1., 4., 2., 0., 2., 2.,
        1., 3., 4., 4., 5., 1., 5., 6., 1., 3., 1., 3., 0., 1., 6., 1., 2., 0.,
        3., 2., 2., 3., 4., 3., 3., 2., 3., 2., 2., 3., 4., 3., 2., 0., 3., 1.,
        1., 3., 1., 4., 7., 2., 2., 1., 1., 1., 2., 3., 3., 2., 2., 3., 1., 3.,
        3., 1., 1., 3., 1., 2., 7., 3., 1., 6.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([2., 2., 4., 2., 5., 1., 2., 4., 2., 2., 2., 5., 1., 2., 1., 4., 1., 2.,
        4., 3., 4., 0., 2., 5., 2., 6., 2., 6., 3., 4., 3., 5., 7., 4., 3., 5.,
        1., 3., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 2., 3., 1., 4., 3., 3., 2., 1.,
        6., 9., 2., 1., 6., 3., 1., 5., 1., 6., 2., 2., 6., 2., 4., 2., 4., 3.,
        2., 2., 4., 1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 3., 1., 3., 2., 3., 3., 2., 2., 4., 3.,
        3., 3., 5., 4., 3., 2., 4., 2., 1., 8.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 1 tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([1., 3., 2., 3., 3., 2., 7., 4., 3., 1., 1., 5., 1., 3., 4., 4., 1., 5.,
        1., 3., 3., 1., 4., 3., 0., 4., 4., 2., 4., 1., 2., 4., 3., 2., 3., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 2., 5., 1., 2., 1., 2., 2., 3., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3.,
        3., 5., 1., 4., 8., 4., 0., 2., 4., 2., 0., 1., 4., 4., 1., 5., 0., 1.,
        3., 1., 2., 3., 3., 4., 3., 4., 2., 4., 2., 3., 4., 1., 1., 2., 4., 1.,
        1., 0., 0., 0., 4., 3., 1., 3., 4., 3.])
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Final Result  tensor([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
Inside PredictionLoss fn : Sum Dim 0 tensor([[nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan,  ..., nan, nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SumBackward1>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the values in `lengths` variable.

In your `cost_function.prediction_loss` you divide the cross entropy loss by the length of each sequece: `(torch.sum(tmp_tensor,dim=1)).float()/  lengths.float()`.
However, if you look at the values of your `lengths` tensor:

> ```
> Inside PredictionLoss fn : lengths tensor([5., 3., 4., 1., 3., 1., 4., 0., 5., 4., 2., 1., 3., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3.,
>    2., 4., 3., 5., 5., 4., 1., 1., 3., 0., 2., 1., 6., 5., 1., 1., 2., 4.,
>    4., 5., 2., 3., 2., 4., 1., 4., 2., 1., 3., 1., 4., 3., 3., 9., 2., 2.,
>    4., 1., 4., 4., 2., 1., 2., 5., 2., 0., 3., 1., 3., 2., 1., 6., 1., 0.,
>    4., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 3., 3., 2., 5., 1., 0., 1., 1., 2., 4., 1., 3.,
>    7., 3., 1., 3., 1., 5., 6., 3., 3., 1.])
> ```

You will notice that some of the entries are **0**(!). The corresponding values in the loss function are also zero (no loss for zero-length sequence). When you divide zero by zero you get `nan`.

---

Some good practices for coding:

1. If possible, use library functions instead of re-implementing things. These functions are usually tested and optimized and are more numerically stable.
   For instance, you can use [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) that combines both the cross entropy loss and the softmax in a numerically robust manner.
2. the variable `lengths` used for loss computation is not explicitly an argument of the loss function or a class member. You should make it an explicit argument.

Comment: I checked the lengths tensor again, its size is > 0. This pytorch code is ported from theano. Here is the original file - https://github.com/mp2893/doctorai/blob/master/doctorAI.py

Comment: @joel even when size of `lengths` is > 0, one of the _values_ in `lengths` might be zero - you divide by these values.